# MySQL + SSRS | Stored Procedure only returns one single row

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, odbc

I'm working on several reports for SSRS written in MySQL via ODBC Adapter. For some reason, Stored Procedures only return a single row of data instead of an expected set of data.

Below is the same stored procedure when ran on an SQL Editor:

[image]

And below is the stored procedure's execution result when SSRS tries to run it (both on Query Designer and Report Viewer):

[image]

I have also set parameters properly as far as i can tell:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of OBDC driver are you using?

Comment: @SQLBobScot i have 8.00.17.00 for MySQL 8.0 ANSI/Unicode on x64 and x86

Comment: When I googled there was an article about an older version (v5 I think) which due to a bug the result set returned was only one row.

Comment: Is this only happening with Stored procedures?  Or do you see the same issue if you use a select statement, that is with a select statement you expect many rows and only 1 is returned?

Comment: select statement works fine for me though. it only happens with stored procedures, i did also bumped across an article telling about that bug around v5, but it didn't mention about succeeding versions being affected still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i wasn't able to find an exact answer as to why this happens on SSRS with MySQL via ODBC. What i was able to find was a workaround:

by executing the command as an `Expression` rather than as a *raw query* via the `Query Editor`:

[image]
[image]

Now the only caveat for this is that `the DataSet Fields wouldn't be automatically generated, and that you have to plot them all manually`. A good workaround for this is to first run a blank/null query with only the column names (i.e.: SELECT NULL 'column_name_1', NULL 'column_name_2') then later change the query source to Expression. The good thing about using expression is that you only need minor knowledge about how it works and it reduces the confusion with ODBC '?' Parameters.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this exact issue was fixed by deleting the Matrix-created tablix and switching to a regular ssrs Table in the report page.

Do NOT use a Matrix Tablix in SSRS for MySQL parameterized stored procedures.

Use a Table.

I believe the problem is with how Matrix tablixes create or expect groups for the data rows.